# Extend BIM 360 Doc web UI with extra doc-related action

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

In BIM 360 Docs web interface, I would like to add a way to trigger a action relative to each selected document. In practice it is about issuing a web request to a custom endpoint that then takes care of the job.

For example: upon user action (click custom link or select context menu entry) automatically perform a copy of the selected file(s) to a predefined folder.

Comment: I hate to disappoint you, it has not support to customize BIM360 Docs web interface. For your requirement, the only way I can think of is to enclose some hyperlink property with the object in source model, while it will be tedious and it would be text format in the panel.

Comment: another thing is Partner Card of BIM360. It is a product feature in Insights module. It allows the 3rd party app be imbedded in BIM360 insight interface. In side your app, it can load the models from BIM360, and do any customization, including monitoring clicking. While all are within your app actually. This is a help about Partner Card: https://help.autodesk.com/view/BIM360D/ENU/?guid=BIM360D_Insight_About_Partner_Data_and_Analytics_Supported_Partner_Cards_Reference_html

Comment: Thanks for your reply @XiaodongLiang.
Maybe your first suggestion. Not sure if I understand. Can the link will be made clickable or will it be just dead text that one need to copy/paste in the browser?

Comment: yes, that might be dead text that the user has to copy paste, as the default attributes value is presented as pure text..